# How to show complete window titles in Gnome overview?

Tags: debian, gnome3, super-key

When doing scientific computation, I need many figures, often >50. 
When I press super, I get Gnome overview where the titles are often not useful etc in Fig. 1.

Fig. 1 a small sample of my Gnome overview with many windows where you see that `Figure 34: P...` is not useful

[image]

It would be really nice if the complete figure title was popping out when you move your cursor on top of the figure in Gnome overview.

OS: Debian 8.5 6 bit
Window manager: Gnome 3.14
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA

Comment: does this help you? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/529/windows-overview-tooltips/

Comment: @lesmana I put `on` there from Firefox. Allowed the gnome site to install from the website. Still waiting but see no effect. I will restart soon. - - Feel free to make your comment an answer. - - Any other gadgets/widgets/... are welcome which could help scientific data analysis! Any ruler, angle measurer would be more more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No supported solution exists in Gnome 3.14. 
Let's home the coming release of Gnome at Q1 2017 helps the situation.

Answer (score 1):

this extension claims to do what you want: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/529/windows-overview-tooltips/

> Makes the title of the window to display its full content when the mouse hovers over the window, in the activities view.

Comment: I installed the application by Gnome extension website but I do not see its being activated. I restarted the system but nothing. In the browser, the extension is `on`. - - How can you test if the addon work?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot help you further. I tried installing myself and it gives no error message but it also does not show up as installed. Based on the comments the author seems to have abandoned the extension years ago. Maybe this will help you: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions

Answer (score 0):

Another Gnome extension called **Always Show Titles In Overview**

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1689/always-show-titles-in-overview/

Works in Debian 11 (Gnome 3.38.x).

Comment: This shows the titles of all windows (rather than just the one you hover on) but long titles are still cut short with an ellipsis.